# Robolectric not finding resources for flavors with different app IDs

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing, robolectric

In Android Studio, I am writing unit tests with Robolectric for multiple flavors, and it seems that I can only access the resources from the tests of the flavor with the default application ID.

My test directory structure is:

```
-src
  ...
  - test (these tests will run on all flavors)
      - java
          - com.example.main
              - UnitTest.java
  - testDefault (these tests will only run on flavor "main")
      - java
          - com.example.main
              - DefaultUnitTest.java
  - testOtherFlavor (these tests will only run on flavor "otherFlavor")
      - java
          - com.example.otherflavor
              - OtherFlavorUnitTest.java
  - main
    ...
    - res
      - values
        - strings.xml
  - otherflavor
    - res
      - values
        - strings.xml
```

In my build.gradle I have

```
productFlavors {
  default{}
  otherFlavor {
    applicationId "com.example.otherflavor"
    versionNameSuffix "-otherFlavor"
  }
}
```

My test is the following:

```
package com.example.otherflavor;

import android.context.Context;
import com.example.main.R;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;
import org.robolectric.RuntimeEnvironment;

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(packageName = com.example.otherflavor)
public class OtherFlavorUnitTest {

    private Context contextMock;

    @Test
    public void test() {

        contextMock = RuntimeEnvironment.application.getApplicationContext();

        System.out.println(contextMock.getString(R.string.someString));

    }

}
```

`someString` is located in both strings.xml files with different values, so that when running the flavor "otherflavor" the value of its strings.xml overrides that of the default flavor. The problem is that when I run this code in the DefaultUnitTest.java (with the package names accordingly changed) the test passes, however when I run this code in the OtherFlavorUnitTest.java I get:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7f0e0059 in packages [com.example.otherflavor, android]
```

**However** if I remove "`applicationId "com.example.otherflavor"`" from the build.gradle the tests pass (and the resource retrieved by getString() is indeed the resource of otherFlavor not of the default flavor).

Does someone know why Robolectric cannot find resources when the flavor has a different App ID?

Comment: Your question will be much clearer if you use real Gradle syntax. I am referring to `applicationId [Flavor 1 app ID]`. I understand that you want to obfuscate your actual application id. However, `[]` is not correct syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have updated the question

Comment: Where is the XML file that defines `R.string.someString`?

Comment: I've added it to the directory tree in my question. It is present in two xml files, one for each flavor, and the otherflavor one overrides that of the default flavor when running the app.

Comment: Please show the import for `R` in `OtherFlavorUnitTest`.

Comment: Does the error occur when you run `OtherFlavorUnitTest`?

Comment: Yes it happens when I run OtherFlavorUnitTest. I've added the imports to my question.

Comment: Try importing `com.example.otherflavor.R` instead. If that fixes it, I will write up an answer with some detailed explanation later today.

Comment: When I try it I says `Cannot resolve symbol 'R'`. `com.example.otherflavor` appears in grey and `R` appears in red

Comment: Clean the project and rebuild? Check your XML files for any errors that will cause R to not be generated.

Comment: Also, are you running the tests in Android Studio or from the command-line? If you are in AS, do you have `otherFlavor` selected in the Build Variants window?

Comment: Unfortunately cleaning and rebuilding is no use. The XML files seem fine, the app does run without problems and uses them. I'm running the tests in Android Studio and I am selecting otherFlavor (actually the icon to run the test doesn't appear otherwise).

Comment: I think the problem has more to do with Robolectric and might have something to do with this: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1623 
It's not the same exception and it's a bit old now but their problems also vanished when they removed the application ID of the flavor. I've tried the solutions posted there and they don't work in my case unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that `test` must be flexible enough to run its tests no matter what the `applicationId` is set to. When done correctly, you select the flavor from the Build Variant window. Then the tests run against the currently selected flavor. Alternatively, you can run `./gradlew testFlavor` or `./gradlew testDefault` from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class to be a provider of the resource in each flavor test directory so each file will have a import matching the aplicationId like com.example.myapp.flavorOne.test.R or flavorTwo.test.R
and then from test class that would be on androidTest(the main test directory) you can get the resource from the resource provider you created matching the build variant (flavor) you are